# How to order a dataframe based on the number of similar characters in 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns, 2 of which need to be compared:

```
id.       chars

72        abc
73        drgc
74        sd

id.       names

72        abrdc
73        dgc
74        sdk
```

I want to order the entire dataframe based on the number of similar, consecutive characters in these 2 columns.

For example, row 72 has 2 similar, consecutive characters ("ab"). Row 73 has 1 such character ("d"). And row 74 has 2 ("sd"). Hence, I need the order of the dataframe to be either: rows [72,74,73], or [74,72,73]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the consecutive character from the beginning of the strings :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'chars': ['abc','drgc','sd'], 'names': ['abrdc','dgc','sdk']}, index=[72,73,74])

def get_max_consecutive_characters(x):
    result = 0
    i = 0
    while i < min(len(x.chars),len(x.names)) and x.chars[i] == x.names[i]:
        result += 1
        i += 1
    return result

df['consecutive_characters'] = df.apply(get_max_consecutive_characters,axis=1)
df = df.sort_values('consecutive_characters', ascending=False).drop(columns=['consecutive_characters'])
df
```

|  | chars | names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 72 | abc | abrdc |
| 74 | sd | sdk |
| 73 | drgc | dgc |